# Converting a large wrongly created csv file into a tab delimited file using python and pandas

Tags: python, regex, csv, pandas

I have a very large csv file (>3GB, > 75million rows).
Problem is, it should not have been created as csv, but tab delimited.
The file has two columns, a string, and an integer. However, the string can have commas (for example: "Yes, it is very nice"), so, now the file may look like this, and it does not have a consistent number of columns and I cannot read it with pandas read_csv.

```
STRING                    CODE      
This is nice                1       
That is also nice           2       
Yes                  it is very nice    3   
I love everything           4
```

I am trying to convert it a tab delimited file, by changing the last comma into a tab. Since the file is huge, I cannot read it into memory. This is what I tried.
I read the file in chunks:

```
for ch in pandas.read_table("path", chunksize=256)
```

I define a function, myfunc, as follows:

```
li = s.rsplit(",", 1)
ret = "\t".join(li)
ret.rsplit("\t", 1)
```

Now, for each chunk I do something like:

```
data["STRING,CODE"] = data["STRING,CODE"].map(lambda x: x.myfunc(x))
data.to_csv("tmp.csv", sep="\t")
```

and I get something like:

```
     STRING                                 CODE
0   "This is nice   1   
1   "That is also nice      
2   "Yes                                it is very nice 3"
3   "I love everything  4"
```

Which is nothing like what I want. The entries are not separated the way I want, I get extra indices, and extra quotation marks. Besides, even after I am able to fix this for one chunk, I need to go back and append to the csv file to recreate the whole file.
Sorry this is messy, but I am lost. Any help?

File:

```
STRING,CODE
This is nice,1
That is also nice,2
Yes,it is very nice,3
I love everything,4
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet from the actual file you have (which includes one of these issues) and what you expect the output to be?

That way we don't have to guess whether a solution will handle (some) of your data.

Comment: Isn't that what I did? The example I posted shows the issue, the 3rd string has a comma in it, so, when it was saved as a csv file, that string is now split into two columns, and the code is moved to a third column. I want to move it a tab delimited file, so that commas in the strings will not affect the file. If this does not answer your question, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Not really a pandas issue.

Comment: The reference you have is an example of the incorrectly parsed file, not the file itself. The file itself will have the fields separated by commas. It's not something one can't fix, but if you want people to test their answers, the easier you make that the more likely they will.

Comment: @ashishsingal True, it is just that I was thinking of using pandas. But you are right.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Got it! See edit, I hope that is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need pandas here. Just iterate through the lines of the file and write the fixed lines to a new file.

```
with open('new.csv', 'w') as newcsv:
    with open('file.csv') as csvf:
        for line in csvf:
            head, _, tail = line.strip().rpartition(',')
            newcsv.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(head, tail))
```

This should get the job done.

Comment: Right, I was using pandas and did not think of an easier solution. This should work, I will try it (just need to add "w" in the first open).

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to use python:

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\),/\1\t/' $INPUT
```

does an inplace replacement of the last `,` in the line with a `/t`.

If you want to preserve the input:

```
sed 's/\(.*\),/\1\t/' $INPUT > $OUTPUT
```

I suspect this would be faster than running it through python, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I am on windows

Comment: @user then python should suffice. I'll leave this here for future viewers.

Comment: I think it is a good answer for people on Unix, thanks (gave you +1)